# How to check if data frame exists in R environment?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add rows to a data frame if it exists, or assign it to initial data frame in case it doesn't exists. I have tried `exists()`, `missing()`, etc, but nothing is working for me.

```
exists(data) && is.data.frame(get(data))
```

> Error in exists(data) : object 'data' not found

Any help would be highly appreciated.
I am trying to do something like

```
if(exists(data))
    data <- rbind(data,new_data)
  else
    data <- new_data
```

Comment: What kind of code are you writing that you don't know if an object exists?

Comment: I think you should use missing() inside the function not exists('data')

Answer (score 13):

If you read [the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/exists.html) you’ll see that it says that `exists` requires

> a variable name (given as a character string).

In other words, write:

```
exists('data') && is.data.frame(get('data'))
```